# Delete row in GridView using Two DataKeys in condition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to delete a row in GridView and database as well.. I already have a stored procedure for the delete, the method is also created, but my problem is how can i use Two datakeys for my `where` clause. I've search and saw a lot of answers but they are using CommandArgument and that is applicable only in 1 datakeys.

I want something like this.

`DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID = Variable1 AND Name = Variable2`

What i want is how can i retrieve the values of 2 datakeys in GridView if i set DataKeys like: `DataKeys="ID, Name"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution on this link:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Multiple-DataKeyNames-DataKeys-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-examples.aspx

here is what exactly im looking for..

```
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = TryCast(TryCast(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer GridViewRow).RowIndex

    Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(rowIndex).Values(0))`
    Dim Name As String = GridView1.DataKeys(rowIndex).Values(1).ToString()`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(if I correctly understood you)

stored procedure

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[Procedure_Name](
   @Variable1 type(),  
   @Variable2 type()    --you can add as many variables as you want, but then you have to add them in c# code as a parameters.        
   ) as

delete from Table_Name
where Table_Name.Variable1 = @Variable1 AND Table_Name.Variable2 = @Variable2
```

with button in aspx code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteSomething" runat="server" Text="Delete Something" OnClick="btnDeleteSomething_Click"/>
```

then in c# codebehind

```
protected void btnDeleteSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_NAME"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure_Name", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection.Open();          
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Variable1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 70(its example with varchar)).Value = Variable1.Text(every Textbox, or label, or dropdownlist)           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Variable2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID]" - For example if u want do delete with parameter focused on user;
        try
        {
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }           
    }        
}
```

And it works fine without Datakeys at all. If u want to do it "with" then u have to add ControlParameter in your SqlDataSource. Hope it's going to help you.

Comment: nope .. what i want is how can i get the values of two datakeys , your example above is passing the values from textbox, dropdwon.. etc. , i already have the sp , what i need is the c# or vb syntax on how can i get the values of two datakeys declared in gridview

Comment: finally i found the solution on my problem , i posted it in answer to share.. anyways thanks for the response, much appreciated. Thanks